# Stored procedure for multiple ouput

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Say I have a table `USER` exactly like below:

```
 User    |   Password   |   Last_Update       |  Access
 --------+--------------+---------------------+-------------
 John        Gjh56fs        July 1st, 2017       Admin
 Mike        5hD75AR        June 21st, 2017      Read Only
```

This table will always have these two records and only password and last update will change occasionally. An external process needs the User and Pass of both users via a stored procedure call.

What is the best way to do this? Can we do a stored procedure to return both user's and passwords? Do we need to make 2 for both records? Do I need to make 4 for each user/pass individually? I guess I am wondering if a stored procedure can handle multiple output because I never personally did this.

This is for an Oracle database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are just confused with stored scalar function and stored procedure. A `stored procedure` can return scalar value, a table result set as well as multiple result sets. With that below sample is a valid stored procedure

```
create procedure mysp
as
begin
select * from tbl1;
select * from tbl2;
end
```

Finally, a piece of suggestion don't store password as plain text in database.

Comment: I have no control over the contents of a archaic table.